# How to filter outlook messages by attachment name or subject using “Microsoft Graph” rest API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

We have integrated outlook to our iOS application using Microsoft Graph API. We have a use case where we have to filter outlook messages by attachment name or by subject. We are using query parameters to hit graph API.

[Link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#search-parameter) to microsoft documentation.

As per above documentation, `$search` parameter is used to filter outlook messages. When are hitting below API, we are getting wrong responses. It’s returning messages which have “Test Mail” in both subject and message body. But it should return only the messages whose subject line is “Test Mail”.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="subject:Test Mail”
```

The same problem we are facing when we filter messages by attachment name, by hitting below API. In fact we are getting a empty response in this case.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search=“attachments:test.png”
```

Is the above URL formation is correct? Why we’re not getting desired response? Please help us out on this.

Comment: If you are implementing according to the documentation then you should probably contact Microsoft for support.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error regarding the subject search in the graph explorer:
When I search for
_/v1.0/me/messages?$search="subject:north"&$Select=Id,subject,body_
the first message 'Northwind Traders Proposal' contains the word 'sending'
When I search for 'sending' 
with _/v1.0/me/messages?$search="subject:sending"&$Select=Id,subject,body_
the result is empty []. 
Is there maybe something I did different?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For [searching](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/query_parameters#search-parameter) Subject only, you can use:

```
/v1.0/me/messages?$search="subject:search term"
```

or a filter:

```
/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=contains(subject, 'my search term')
```

(in this method the search term must exactly match a portion of the subject string)

For searching attachments only, you must use the keyword 'attachment' instead of 'attachments' ([exchange documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn774955(v=exchg.160).aspx)):

```
/v1.0/me/messages?$search="attachment:search term"
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the solution.
This solved my use case. 
/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=contains(subject, 'my search term')

But subject and attachment search still not working. 
/v1.0/me/messages?$search="subject:search term"
/v1.0/me/messages?$search="attachment:search term"

Does it have anything to do with ' and "" ?

Comment: This is weird this should normally work without any problems. Can you reproduce the same behaviour in the [GraphExplorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=me/messages?$search=%22attachment:.docx%22%26$expand=attachments%26$select=id,subject,attachments&method=GET&version=v1.0)?